# "django.db.utils.IntegrityError: " NOT NULL constraint failed: adoptions_pet.submission_data

Tags: python, django

I am trying to fill my adoption website with a testing data from a CSV file

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed:
>   adoptions_pet.submission_data

i run 
**python manage.py makemigrations** 

 Then  i run 
**python manage.py migrate**
After that i wrote a command to run the a scripting file called **load_pet_data.py** the will insert the testing data to the file the command was 

**python manage.py load_pet_data**

After some search i tried to delete the **"db.sqlit3"** and re-migrate but i still getting the same error
 - **This is the load_pet_data.py script file**

```
from csv import DictReader
from datetime import datetime
from django.core.management import BaseCommand
from adoptions.models import Pet, Vaccine
from pytz import UTC


DATETIME_FORMAT = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'

VACCINES_NAMES = [
    'Canine Parvo',
    'Canine Distemper',
    'Canine Rabies',
    'Canine Leptospira',
    'Feline Herpes Virus 1',
    'Feline Rabies',
    'Feline Leukemia'
]

ALREADY_LOADED_ERROR_MESSAGE = """
If you need to reload the pet data from the CSV file,
first delete the db.sqlite3 file to destroy the database.
Then, run `python manage.py migrate` for a new empty
database with tables"""


class Command(BaseCommand):
    # Show this when the user types help
    help = "Loads data from pet_data.csv into our Pet model"

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        if Vaccine.objects.exists() or Pet.objects.exists():
            print('Pet data already loaded...exiting.')
            print(ALREADY_LOADED_ERROR_MESSAGE)
            return
        print("Creating vaccine data")
        for vaccine_name in VACCINES_NAMES:
            vac = Vaccine(name=vaccine_name)
            vac.save()
        print("Loading pet data for pets available for adoption")
        for row in DictReader(open('./pet_data.csv')):
            pet = Pet()
            pet.name = row['Pet']
            pet.submitter = row['Submitter']
            pet.species = row['Species']
            pet.breed = row['Breed']
            pet.description = row['Pet Description']
            pet.sex = row['Sex']
            pet.age = row['Age']
            raw_submission_date = row['submission date']
            submission_date = UTC.localize(
                datetime.strptime(raw_submission_date, DATETIME_FORMAT))
            pet.submission_date = submission_date
            pet.save()
            raw_vaccination_names = row['vaccinations']
            vaccination_names = [name for name in raw_vaccination_names.split('| ') if name]
            for vac_name in vaccination_names:
                vac = Vaccine.objects.get(name=vac_name)
                pet.vaccinations.add(vac)
            pet.save()
```

**and this is the application "models.py" where my models written**

```
from django.db import models

class Pet(models.Model):
    SEX_CHOICES=[('M','Male'),('F','Female')]
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    submitter=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    species=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    breed=models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    sex=models.CharField(choices=SEX_CHOICES,max_length=1,blank=True)
    submission_data=models.DateTimeField()
    age=models.IntegerField(null=True)
    vaccinations=models.ManyToManyField('Vaccine',blank=True)
class Vaccine (models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

**This is a screen shoot for the project construction may it help** 
[image: This is a screen shoot for the project construction may it help]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django - IntegrityError - Not null constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27881947/django-integrityerror-not-null-constraint)

Comment: i already add a "blank=True" with the many to many field in 
"vaccinations=models.ManyToManyField('Vaccine',blank=True)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo. It should be `pet.submission_data` instead of `pet.submission_date = submission_date`.

Answer (score 1):

you have given the field name as `submission_date`

```
            submission_date = UTC.localize(
                datetime.strptime(raw_submission_date, DATETIME_FORMAT))
            pet.submission_date = submission_date
```

but your model has

```
submission_data=models.DateTimeField()
```